# Directional derivative question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the limit
$$\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{f(a + sx) - f(a)}{s}$$
if it exists is called the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ in the direction $x$ and is denoted $D_x f(a)$.   I want to show that $D_{tx}f(a) = tD_xf(a)$.   Help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be using the variable $t$ in two different contexts. It would be good to have another variable.

Comment: That actually makes things a lot clearer.  I was misinterpreting this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I’d prefer to give a hint, but I can’t think of one that doesn’t give the game away. It’s a straightforward computation: by definition

$$\begin{align*}D_{tx}f(a)&=\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{f(a+stx)-f(a)}s\\\\
&=t\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{f(a+stx)-f(a)}{st}\\\\
&=t\lim_{st\to 0}\frac{f(a+stx)-f(a)}{st}\\\\
&=tD_xf(a)\;.
\end{align*}$$

**Added:** Note that this makes sense only if $t\ne 0$. If $t=0$, the difference quotient is identically $0$, since $f(a+stx)=f(a)$, and its limit is therefore $0$, which is indeed $tD_{tx}f(a)$.

Comment: +1. A nitpick though. You might want to argue the case $t=0$ separately.

Comment: @Marvis: You’re absolutely right; thanks.