# Proving definition of directional derivative $\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{f(a + sx) - f(a)}{s} = f'(a)x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition

Inspired by: [Directional derivative question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157614/directional-derivative-question)

I had long sought for a proof $$\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{f(a + sx) - f(a)}{s} = f'(a)x$$

But whenever I look it up, I always get some multivariable calculus stuff i.e. Paul's online notes http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx which is some computational multivariable calculus stuff assuming $f(x,y)$

Can someone please show that the above relation is true or provide me a reference for this formulation of the directional derivative? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a multivariable calculus question.  [Math Insight](http://mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_derivation) covers Calc III topics pretty well, IMO.

Comment: There seems to me that there is an inherent flaw in your question. You cannot prove a definition. It is not a theorem. It is simply a definition. It is simply the way $f'$ is defined. Asking to prove what you asked is akin to asking "How do I prove that an even number is divisible by $2$". It's just the way it's defined.

Comment: @OriaGruber I think they want a proof of the equality there.

Comment: @OriaGruber The limit on the LHS of that equation is the definition of the directional derivative.  OP wants a proof that it equals the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply L'Hopital's rule if you know $f$ is continuously differentiable.

$$\lim\limits_{s \to 0} \frac{f(a+sx)-f(a)}{s}=\lim\limits_{s \to 0} f'(a+sx)x=f'(a)x$$